# Windows 8 Bluetooth Low Energy - Custom driver required

Tags: windows, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect a Glucose and Heartrate monitor LE devices using Windows 8.  It is being detected just fine and default LE is used for the device.  I'm trying to use the sample BLE http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Bluetooth-LE-Metro-sample-a2ba1b5b but getting 80070057 error.

I have read some post that a custom driver is required. I run it using the sample in Mac and it works just fine. The sample application was able to use the device without any issues.  Is there a way to access and use the device without creating a custom driver?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The sample is just a facade to the user. Driver is always needed in order to communicate with hardware. For some standard devices the OS might include a default driver (e.g., standard Web cam) with a predefined set of functionality but for all the rest a vendor-supplied driver is required.